# Log into one website, then automatically to all other websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web

We have two websites. What we want is for a user to log into one website, then, when he goes to another website, he no longer needs to login.

What I did was to place an image on the web page of the **first website**, which is shown after user logs in. That image is downloaded from the **second website**. In the action method in the **second website** which serves the image, I place an authentication cookie and logs user in.

Contradicting outcome:

1. After user logs into the **first website**, he still has to log into the **second website**. Although the image was indeed downloaded from the **second website**, it did not insert an **.ASPXAUTH** cookie.
2. However, if I manually invoke that action method by placing the URL of that action method into browser and hit enter, the second website did insert a **.ASPXAUTH** cookie, and I no longer need to log into the **second website**.

What's the difference between the web page on the **first website** downloading the image, and me doing it manually?

Comment: use the same machine key in both the web.config to achieve this, as explained here: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1791c5e3-4087-4e92-a460-51c5c4221f49/any-forms-auth-changes-in-45?forum=Offtopic

Comment: Thanks but no effect.

Comment: Are the two sites sharing the same domain? If they are not the the auth cookies are not available for the second website to access. The outcome from your scenario one is that the cookie from the second website domain will not be stored in browser if the page loaded is from the first website.

Comment: I see! It must be the reason then. No these two sites do not have the same domain. Is there anyway to achieve what I wanted to achieve? Or, if the first site is "abc.mysite.com" and the second site is "xyz.mysite.com", will it work?

Comment: One way I can think of is to load the image from the second website in an iFrame of the first website. That way the cookie can be set correctly for the second website domain.